# Using OR & AND in COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-statements

I would like to include an `"AND"` condition for one of the conditions I have in my `COUNTIFS` clause.

Something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A196;{"Yes"or "NO"};J1:J196;"Agree")
```

So, it should return the number of rows where:

```
 (A1:A196 is either "yes" or "no") AND (J1:j196 is "agree")
```

Answer (score 27):

You could just add a few `COUNTIF` statements together:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A196,"yes")+COUNTIF(A1:A196,"no")+COUNTIF(J1:J196,"agree")
```

This will give you the result you need.

**EDIT**

Sorry, misread the question. Nicholas is right that the above will double count. I wasn't thinking of the `AND` condition the right way. Here's an alternative that should give you the correct results, which you were pretty close to in the first place:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A196,{"yes","no"},J1:J196,"agree"))
```

Comment: I think this formula is incorrect because it will double count lines where column `A` is `yes` and column `J` is `agree`, for instance.

Comment: I agree with Nicholas.

Comment: Can you use braces like that on a `COUNTIFS` function? I'm testing it and it only counts the occurrences of the first value inside the braces.

Comment: Whoops! Missed a step. Corrected formula above.

Comment: I was trying this out and it only worked partially for me.  For some reason it only will match whatever is first within the curly brackets no matter what I do and not the second item.

Comment: @Endyo, This works for me using Excel 2013 on Windows 8. It doesn't work with LibreOffice Calc on Ubuntu 14, however. What's your setup?

Comment: Wait I found my problem.  I forgot the "SUM" at the beginning.  I'd been messing around with this for so long I didn't even see that part of it.

Comment: I think the issue for me is that it adds these together rather than giving me the total where both sets of criteria are true.  I am trying to get the count of rows where both two different column criteria are true at the same time.  So for the example here: like if A1 = "yes" AND J1 = "agree" it would be one.  I'm getting one for each of those.

Comment: Or maybe it just really screws up when you use not equal.

Comment: Not sure I totally follow you. As is, the formula should give you a count of 1 for each instance where A1 is "yes" or "no," and J1 is "agree." If you've changed it to something like `"<>"&{"yes","no"}` and the value in A1 is "maybe," I could see how it would give you a count of 2. Sounds like it might be worth posting a new question with an example of your data and what changes you've made to the formula.

Comment: Need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a more efficient solution to your question, but following formula should do the trick:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(J1:J196,"agree",A1:A196,"yes"),COUNTIFS(J1:J196,"agree",A1:A196,"no"))
```

Comment: Thank you but yea exactly I am looking for a more efficient solution instead of having to write countifs multiple times.

Comment: So are you saying that this solution doesn't work for you solely on the basis of using two `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: No Nicholas, it is not the solution I am looking for. If you look at my question text more carefully, you can see my pseudo formula which has only one COUNTIFS. My question is more like how we can use an OR for one of the conditions inside the AND clause.

Comment: Understood. As far as I know, however, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

In a more general case:

```
N( A union B) = N(A) + N(B) - N(A intersect B) 
= COUNTIFS(A1:A196,"Yes",J1:J196,"Agree")+COUNTIFS(A1:A196,"No",J1:J196,"Agree")-A1:A196,"Yes",A1:A196,"No")
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is doing the sum:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A196,{"yes","no"},B1:B196,"agree"))
```

or know its not the countifs but the sumproduct will do it in one line:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A196={"yes","no"})*(j1:j196="agree")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using array formula.

```
=SUM(COUNT(IF(D1:D5="Yes",COUNT(D1:D5),"")),COUNT(IF(D1:D5="No",COUNT(D1:D5),"")),COUNT(IF(D1:D5="Agree",COUNT(D1:D5),"")))
```

PRESS = CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: Thanks for the CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Answer (score -1):

i found i had to do something akin to

```
=(countifs (A1:A196,"yes", j1:j196, "agree") + (countifs (A1:A196,"no", j1:j196, "agree"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.