# COUNTIFS with multiple criteria and with OR condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the cells based on some criteria as shown in the image but it's returning 0 value.

Formula: =COUNTIFS(All_PRs!R:R,S189,All_PRs!I:I,"2",All_PRs!J:J,{"O","IC"})

[image]

Comment: Wrap it in `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: Just `SUM` will do - no need for SP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OR & AND in COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655685/using-or-and-in-countifs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a range, just SUM() it and you should be good.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(All_PRs!R:R,S189,All_PRs!I:I,"2",All_PRs!J:J,{"O","IC"}))
```

Comment: I had tried using `SUM` but don't know what was wrong, working fine.

Comment: Hard to say, the same effect can be achieved with SUMPRODUCT() without the COUNTIFS()
=SUMPRODUCT((ALL_PRs!J:J={"O","IC"})*(ALL_PRs!I:I=2)*(ALL_PRs!R:R=S189))

Comment: Thank you so much, will give a try!